# htaccess URLRewrite virtual directories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to create pretty urls (slashed params) using 2 virtual (not real directory paths.)

For some reason, when I include virtual paths, the RewriteRules do not catch the requested URLs.

Current code does not work: (no rewrite happens)

```
RewriteRule ^virtualpathONE/file/(.*)$ realpath1/file.php?param=$1
RewriteRule ^virtualpathTWO/file/(.*)$ realpath2/file.php?param=$1
```

However without any virtual paths it works:

```
RewriteRule ^file/(.*)$ realpath1/file.php?param=$1
```

How can I use two virtual paths in my htaccess file?

The final output should be:

```
mysite.com/virtualpathone/file/param/100
```

and

```
mysite.com/virtualpathtwo/file/param/100
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What URL did you use when using virtual path and what error you got?

Comment: Thanks for comment. No error. Just a normal page loads without the url being rewritten.  I used site.com/virtualpathone/file/param/100

Answer (score 0):

Try this .htaccess in your DocumentRoot:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^virtualpathONE/file/(.*)$ realpath1/file.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^virtualpathTWO/file/(.*)$ realpath2/file.php?param=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Just tried it. Url doesnt change. If I manually type pretty url into address bar like so: site.com/virutalpathone/file/param/100 I get a page can not be found error.

Comment: Try this exact URL `site.com/virutalpathONE/file/100`. Do you have more rules in this htaccess?

Comment: And if `http://domain.com/virutalpathONE/file/100` gives 404 then also try: `http://domain.com/realpath1/file.php?param=100`

Comment: Also make sure .htaccess is in root dir i.e. one level above `/realpath1/`